# Prove or disprove: if A, B, and C are sets where A-C = B-C, then A = B.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

This is my first disproof and I have a couple of questions.

1. Can you just disprove with a counterexample?
2. The question doesn't say "for all", does that mean I automatically imply that the claim is "true" for every set?
3. If someone can critique my proof writing and see if there's a better way of writing this proof?

My working:

A = {0,1,2,3,4}
B = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

A $\neq$ B

C = {4,5,6,7,8}

A-C = {0,1,2,3}
B-C = {0,1,2,3}

A = B

Proof:

We will show that claim is false. By negating the initial claim, we can rewrite it as A-C = B-C ^ A $\neq$ B.

Let us consider a set A = {x $\in \mathbb N$ | x $\le$ 5}, B = {x $\in \mathbb N$ | x $\le$ 8} and C = {x $\in \mathbb N$ | x $\ge$ 5 $\cap$ x $\le$ 8}.

By performing A - C we result with a set where A-C={x $\in \mathbb N$ | x $\le$ 4}. Similarly consider the set B-C = {x $\in \mathbb N$ | x $\le$ 4}.

This leads to the conclusion that the claim is false, since the we have proved the negation equivalent as true.

Comment: For sets $A$ and $B$, what does $A-B$ mean, in the context of this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment

> Can you just disprove by a counterexample?

Yes, if you found a counterexample, the claim is false.

> The question doesn't say "for all", does that mean I automatically imply that the claim is "true" for every set?

The claim is an implication $P\implies Q$ whenever the premice are true, the conclusion must also be true. We don't need "for all".

> If someone can critique my proof writing and see if there's a better way of writing this proof?

Your proof is fine. Your three sets respect the hypothesis, but not the conclusion, therefore the claim is false.

Answer (score 2):

1. It can be disproved with a counterexample.
2. We understand the sets A, B and C as arbitrary sets, so if true, the statement holds for all sets A, B and C.
3. What you need to do is to give two different sets such that when you take the difference for each of those with a particular set, the remaining sets are the same set, so the statement is false.

e.g:

$A = (-\infty, 0]$, $B= (-\infty, 1]$, $C= [-2, 1]$

So $A-C = (-\infty, -2)$, $B-C = (-\infty, -2)$ but $A\neq B$